# How to avoid @ as word breaker in SQL server Full Text Search

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

Is there a way to ignore @ as a word breaker for full text in SQL Server 2012/2014. I should be able to search email address in full text search.

Comment: show a sample of what you are trying that isn't working.

Comment: This is problematic because symbols aren't indexed in full text search, so that '@' character will never really be 'findable.'  Either break the search string up into before and after the symbol and search for both terms, or modify all your targets to replace the @ with '_' (which is indexed) and modify your search accordingly.

Comment: select * from sys.dm_fts_parser('test.1234@gmail.com' ,1033 ,0 ,0);